# Calling for directions using google Maps in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an application running on android using a web view.  The code that loads the web page in the web view is below:

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.findPracticeWebView);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl("http://www.womenshealthct.com/mobile/WomensHealth/FindAPractice.html");

There is a javascript call that will get the users current location and give them directions to a specific location.  This code runs as expected from a desktop browser as well as from the browser on the android device.  The directions functionality does not work in the web view.

What have I missed or done wrong?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean, specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue through a post [here](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/) by a gentleman named David Chandler.  I was missing a couple of settings for the webview.